# Why does having two classical registers sometimes only yeild one bit?

Tags: measurement, classical-computing

I was running some  qiskit code on qasm_simulator to test something and I realized that, when I have two separate classical registers, sometimes only one bit is generated, and I'm trying to understand why? If you have two meaurements, but send them to only one classical register, the second one overwrites the first in the final output. I would expect that if you have two seperate classical registers, both with be displayed in the output but that doesnt always seems to be the case?

Fore example here is some simple code that demonstrates this:

```
#Sending two measurements to one classical register yeilds only outputs of one bit. 
circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[0], creg_c[0])
circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[0], creg_c[0])

job = execute(circuit, backend, shots=8192, memory=True)
output=[]
result_list=job.result().get_memory()
for entry in result_list:
    output.append(int(entry))
print(output)

>>> [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,...]
```

```
#Sending two measurements to two different classical register sometimes yeild two bits and sometimes yeilds one. 
circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[0], creg_c[0])
circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[0], creg_c[1])

job = execute(circuit, backend, shots=8192, memory=True)
output=[]
result_list=job.result().get_memory()
for entry in result_list:
    output.append(int(entry))
print(output)

>>> [0, 10, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 1, 11, 11, 10, 11, 0, 11, 1, 10, 0, 11, 0, 10, 10, 1,...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your convert the bit-strings to integers.

```
output.append(int(entry))
```

Hence, the leading zeros are removed. If you want to keep the bit-string as it is, don't convert it:

```
print(job.result().get_memory())
```